# Почему земля в поговорках сырая?

Tags: этимология, фразеология

Есть достаточно большое количество поговорок, в которых упоминается "сыра земля". Вспомним песенку:

*Разлука, ты разлука,

Чужая сторона.

Никто нас на разлучит,

Лишь мать сыра земля.*

Мне почему-то кажется, что тут не идет речь конкретно о мокрой земле. А о чем же тогда? О какой сырой земле речь?
И сразу еще один вопрос: интересно, почему слово "сырой" означает одновременно и "влажный", и "необработанный"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> мать сыра земля

Может быть потому, что она **рОдит**, тогда когда **сыра**.

.

> почему слово "сырой" означает одновременно и "влажный", и "необработанный"?

Необработанное -- сырое, сырьё. Возможно, с приготовлением пищи как-то связано. Сырое и готовое.

Некоторую аналогию можно провести с английским словом **raw** - сырой, необработанный, неприготовленная пища. (raw materials - сырьё).
Происходит от древнегерманского hrawaz, hrēwaz - сырой. А это в свою очередь от праиндоевропейского krewa- сырое мясо, свежая кровь. Откуда и русское слово *кровь*. (Из англ. [словаря](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/raw))

Возможно, это германское *hrawaz* - мясо кровавое и поэтому сырое (в смысле, влажное). А готовое мясо - уже какое-то другое - сушёное что ли. 
:-) Ну правда с вареным мясом не знаю как эту версию состыковать - оно тоже мокрое.

Answer (score 4):

Из Википедии

Мать — Сыра́ Земля́ — олицетворённая земля в славянской мифологии. Считалась матерью всех живых существ и растений, средоточием плодородия.  Бог-Громовержец (Небо) оплодотворял Землю дождём, после чего она давала (рождала) урожай.

Answer (score 1):

cырой 1 'влажный' и сырой 2 'необработанный' - это два явных омонима, т.е. слова с одинаковым видом и совершенно разным смыслом. Признаем, что среди русских омонимичных прилагательных много случаев, когда они в древности явно имели явно близкий смысл, т.е. имела место полисемия, как например отличный 1 'различающийся' и отличный 2 'имеющий отличие в лучшую сторону'. Но неспециалистам заглядывать в этимологию столь далеко не стоит, достаточно запомнить типовые контексты, в которых эти омонимы употребляются.  
Относительно оборота "сыра земля" - абсолютно правильно замечание, что во всех широтах России земля мокрая уже на 30-50 см в глубину. Поезжайте в Турцию или лучше в тропики. Там красноземы, они вечно сухие, покуда их не польют. Так что в южных странах такого оборота возникнуть не могло.

Answer (score 0):

Сыра земля - термин, который применяется обычно в связи со смертью. В России практически повсеместно достаточно близко к поверхности расположены грунтовые воды. По этой причине даже в сухую погоду на глубине более метра грунт становится влажным, т.е. сырым. Сыра земля - грунт, вырытый из могилы.

Answer (score -1):

По моему небезосновательному и глубокому подозрению все слова, состоящие из трех и более звуков (букв),  образованы сложением нескольких названий предметов, явлений , окружавших пра-пращуров на заре возникновения языков. В качестве примера я приводил значение слова **кора.** Итак, **сыра**, где: ра - это солнце, а сы (су, са) у разных тюркских народов свое - вода. Вот вам и значение: объятая Солнцем и напоенная водой Земля.